# Return empty array (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a condition statement in Ruby. If my array of various numbers is empty or nil, it should return an empty array otherwise it should sort the numbers. This is what I have so far.

```
num == nil || num.empty? ? return num : num.sort!
```

...where num is my array. However I'm getting the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ':'
```

I get this error if num is an array of numbers or nil. I'm not sure why this isn't working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix your code, change what you have to one of the following:

```
num.nil? || num.empty? ? [] : num.sort

num.nil? ? [] : num.sort

(num || []).sort

num.to_a.sort
```

The latter two convert `num` to an empty array if `num` is `nil`, then sort the result. See [NilClass.to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/NilClass.html#method-i-to_a).

Comment: accepted because of that last code snippet. Well done good sir ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is because you put `return num` within a ternary operator construction. Precedence rule does not parse it as you wanted. Remove `return`, and it will not raise an error (although it will not work as you want to; `nil` will be returned when `num` is `nil`). Or, if you want to use `return` only when the condition is satisfied, then you should do `(return num)`.

But for your purpose, a better code is:

```
num.to_a.sort
```

Comment: so is the return just assumed in Ruby?

Comment: Ruby always returns the value of the last executed statement. But if you want to return from somewhere else than the last statement, `return` comes in handy.

Comment: Or, just use `if`/`then`/`else` whose precedence is pretty much always what you would expect: `if num == nil || num.empty? then return num else num.sort! end`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that you work with an array, just call:

```
Array(num).sort
```

Because it works like this:

```
Array(nil)    #=> []
Array([])     #=> []
Array([1, 2]) #=> [1, 2]
```