# ruby if-else one-liner with "puts" not working

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm trying to do

```
    response = gets.chomp
    response == "a" ? puts "yes" : puts "no"
```

The terminal complains:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    response == "a" ? puts "yes" : puts "no"
                                  ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has *got* be be a duplicate, I swear, I have seen this *exact* question asked at least a dozen times on StackOverflow. However, I can't for the life of me find a canonical duplicate (or *any* duplicate at all, really). Anybody have one handy?

Comment: @JörgWMittag maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/25234521/477037 or its duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/25328481/477037 but the answers don't really explain the limitations of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your error:

```
response == "a" ? puts "yes" : puts "no"
  #=> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input
  #   response == "a" ? puts "yes" : puts "no"
  #                           ^
```

Ruby is looking for the first `puts`' arguments. Since they are not enclosed in parentheses, she assumes they are in a comma-separated list following `puts`. The first one is `"yes"`, but there is no comma following `"yes"`, so an exception is raised.

Let's try:

```
response == "a" ? (puts "yes") : puts "no"
  #=> syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
  #   response == "a" ? (puts "yes") : puts "no"
  #                                          ^
```

(`response == "a" ? puts("yes") : puts "no"` raises the same exception.)

I don't know why this doesn't work. The exception says that it is expecting a block (`do...end` or `{..}`) or a left parentheses (for enclosing arguments) after the second `puts`. [Kernel#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) calls `$stdout.puts`. As `$stdout` returns an `IO` object, [IO#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) is then called, but the doc sheds no light on the problem. Perhaps a reader can offer an explanation.

You could write it as follows:

```
response == "a" ? (puts "yes") : (puts "no")
```

or

```
response == "a" ? puts("yes") : puts("no")
```

or (best, imo)

```
puts response == "a"  ? "yes" : "no"
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you might have some stray backticks in your code, though.

Comment: What's the reason the parentheses are necessary? Why is the terminal complaining when I do it the way I tried above?

Comment: definitely use `puts response == "a"  ? "yes" : "no"` instead

Comment: *"I don't know why this doesn't work"* - I'd say the parser only allows spaces before a block, i.e. `cond ? foo {} : bar {}` works, whereas `cond ? foo 1 : bar 2` doesn't.

Comment: @Stefan, it's only the part following the colon that I don't understand. I don't see why the parser wouldn't parse that as it would any other line of code. Why should it object to `puts 'hi'` after the colon? (Before the colon, yes.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm going to take a look at the parser code if I find some time

Comment: @Stefan, I don't mean to rush you, but have your found time yet?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I totally forgot! I should make a todo list for that kind of research.